# Stability of equilibrium point for an autonomous system of first order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-theory

I'm dealing with the following problem. Determine whether the equilibrium point (0,0) of the following ODE is stable or not.
\begin{cases}
\dot x = xy + x^3,  \\ 
\dot y = -y -2x^2.
\end{cases}
The stability of a equilibrium point is in the liapunov sense, i.e. for any neighborhood $U(x_0)$ of the equilibrium point $x_0$, there exists a $V(x_0)$ contained in $U(x_0)$, s.t. any trajectories starting from $V(x_0)$ is contained in $U(x_0)$.
I guess it could be worked out by constructing some liapunov function but I cannot figure it out now.